# How to copy specific text from the body of the email?

Tags: regex, excel, vba, outlook, regex-group

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFromInbox()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("impMail")
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"

For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "SubjectoftheEmail") > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fixings").Cells(2, 2).Value = olMail.Body

    End If
Next olMail

Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code help me to download whole body of the email but I need specific bold text in cells. The email body is always as follows. The lines are always in the same order. All lines are always present. The all names in email could be known in advance.

> This EMAIL IS ONLY FOR Internal use
>
> Hi
>
> @ABC4: please add the following detail in system (for **12-Jan-2019**):
>
> **12345_ABC_MakOpt --- 264532154.78
>
>   12345_ABC_GAPFee --- 145626547.80**
>
> thanks

´ -----------------------------------------------------
        'get setup
        '-----------------------------------------------------

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rngEmailSubject As Range
    Dim rngInstrumentName As Range
    Dim rngDate As Range
    Dim rngAmount As Range
    Dim arrFixing() As typFixing
    Dim rngValue As Range

    Dim rowIdx As Integer
    Dim ix As Integer
    Dim fixingDate As Date

    With wb.Sheets("FixingFromEmail")

        Set rngInstrumentName = .Range("instrument.name")
        Set rngDate = .Range("Date")
        Set rngAmount = .Range("Amount")

        rowIdx = rngInstrumentName.Row
        ix = 0

        Do While True

            rowIdx = rowIdx + 1
             If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rowIdx, rngInstrumentName.Column).Value) _
        Then

                ix = ix + 1

                ReDim Preserve arrFixing(1 To ix)
                arrFixing(ix).InstrumentName = .Cells(rowIdx, rngInstrumentName.Column).Value
                arrFixing(ix).Date = .Cells(rowIdx, rngDate.Column).Value
                arrFixing(ix).Amount = .Cells(rowIdx, rngAmount.Column).Value


            Else
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop

    End With´
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too vague for a specific answer.  All I can offer is some guidance on the first stages.

You need to decide what is fixed and what is variable.

Is “@ABC4” fixed?  Is “@ABC4: please add the following detail in system (for” fixed?

Are there always two data lines?  Are there multiple data lines of which these are examples?  Is the format of these lines:

```
Xxxxxxx space hyphen hyphen hyphen space amount
```

I would start by splitting the text body into lines.  Almost certainly the lines are broken by Carriage-Return Linefeed.  To test:

```
Dim Count As Long

For Each olMail In olItms

  Debug.Print Replace(Replace(Mid$(olMailBody, 1, 200), vbCr, "{c}"), vbLf, "{l}" & vbLf)
  Count = Count + 1
  If Count >= 10 Then
    Exit For
  End If

Next olMail
```

The output will be something like ten (maximum) copies of:

```
@ABC4: please add the following detail in system (for 12-Jan-2019):{c}{l}
{c}{l}
12345_ABC_MakOpt --- 264532154.78{c}{l}
12345_ABC_GAPFee --- 145626547.80{c}{l}
Are the characters between lines “{c}{l}” or “{l}” or something else?
```

In the code below, replace `vbCR & vbLf` if necessary then run it:

```
Dim Count As Long
Dim InxL As Long
Dim Lines() As String

For Each olMail In olItms

  Lines = Split(olMail.Body, vbCR & vbLf)
  For InxL = 0 to UBound(Lines)
    Debug.Print InxL + 1 & "  " & Lines(InxL)
  Next
  Count = Count + 1
  If Count >= 10 Then
    Exit For
  End If

Next
```

The output will be something like ten (maximum) copies of:

```
0  
1  @ABC4: please add the following detail in system (for 12-Jan-2019):
2  
3  12345_ABC_MakOpt --- 264532154.78
4  12345_ABC_GAPFee --- 145626547.80
5
```

Now you can see the text body as lines.  Note: the first line is number 0.  Is there never a blank line at the top?  Is there always a blank line at the top?  Does it vary?  I am going to assume there is always a blank line at the top.  The following code will need modification if that assumption is incorrect.

If line 1 is “xxxxxxxxxx date):” you could extract the date so:

```
Dim DateCrnt As Date
Dim Pos As Long

DateCrnt = CDate(Left$(Right$(Lines(1), 13), 11))
```

or

```
Pos = InStr(1, Lines(1), "(for ")
DateCrnt = CDate(Mid$(Lines(1), Pos + 5, 11))
```

Note: both these methods depend on the end of the line being just as you show in your example.  If there is any variation you will need code that handles that variation.

You can now split the data lines using code like this:

```
Dim NameCrnt As String
Dim AmtCrnt As Double

For InxL = 3 To UBound(Lines)
  If Lines(InxL) <> "" Then
    Pos = InStr(1, Lines(InxL), " --- ")
    If Pos = 0 Then
      Debug.Assert False   ' Line not formatted as expected
    Else
      NameCrnt = Mid$(Lines(InxL), 1, Pos - 1)
      AmtCrnt = Mid$(Lines(InxL), Pos + 5)
    End If
    Debug.Print "Date="& DateCrnt & "    " & "Name=" & NameCrnt & "   " & "Amount=" & AmtCrnt
  End If
Next
```

Output is:

```
Date=12/01/2019    Name=12345_ABC_MakOpt   Amount=264532154.78
Date=12/01/2019    Name=12345_ABC_GAPFee   Amount=145626547.8
```

**New section showing how to add data from email to worksheet**

This is the second version of this section because the OP changed their mind about the format required.

The code below has been tested but with fake emails I created to look like the one in your question.  So some debugging will probably be necessary.

I created a new workbook and a new worksheet named “Fixings” with the following headings:

[image: Empty worksheet before macro run]

After processing my fake emails, the worksheet looked like:

[image: Worksheet after runs to add data from three daily emails]

The sequence of rows is dependent on the sequence in which emails were found.  You probably want newest first.  Sorting the worksheet is outside the scope of this answer.  Note: it is the column headings which tell the macro which values are to be recorded. If a new line was added to the email, add a new column heading and the value will be saved without changing the macro.

With one exception, I will not explain the VBA statements I have used because it is easy to search online for “VBA xxxxx” and find a specification for statement xxxxx.  The exception is the use of two collections to hold pending data.  The remaining explanations describe the reasons behind my approach.

There will be changes to the requirement although perhaps not for six or twelve months.  For example, a manager will want a different heading or the columns in a different sequence.  You cannot anticipate what changes will be required but you can prepare for changes.  For example, at the top of my code I have:

```
Const ColFixDate As Long = 1
Const ColFixDataFirst As Long = 2
Const RowFixHead As Long = 1
Const RowFixDataFirst As Long = 2
```

I could have written `Cells(Row, 1).Value = Date`.  This has two disadvantages: (1) if the date column is ever moved, you have to search through the code for statements that access it and (2) you have to remember what is in column 1 or 2 or 3 making your code harder to read.  I avoid ever using literals for row or column numbers.  The extra effort to type ColFixDataFirst instead of 2, quickly repays itself.

I notice in the code added to your question, you use named ranges to achieve the same effect.  A problem with VBA is there are often several ways of achieving the same effect.  I prefer constants but each of us must choose our own favourites.

Having worked in a department that processed many emails and workbooks, received from outsiders, that contained useful data, I can tell you that their formats change all the time.  There will be an extra blank line or an existing one will be removed.  There will be extra data or the existing data will be in a different sequence.  The authors make changes they think will be helpful but rarely do anything useful like ask if receivers would like the change or even warn them of the change.  The worst I ever saw was when two numeric columns were reversed and it was not noticed for months.  Fortunately, I was not involved because it was a nightmare backing out the faulty data from our system and then importing the correct data.  I check everything I can think of and refuse to process emails that are not exactly as I expect.  The error messages are all written to the immediate window which is convenient during development.  You may want to use MsgBox or write them to a file.  If the email is processed successfully, it is not deleted; it is moved to a subfolder so it can be retrieved should it ever be needed again.

`olMail` is an Outlook constant.  Do not use `olMail` or any other reserved word as a variable name.

I have used `Session` rather than a NameSpace.  They are supposed to be equivalent but I once had a problem with a NameSpace that I could not diagnose so I no longer use them.

I do not sort the emails since your code does not take advantage of having the emails sorted.  Perhaps you could take advantage of sorting by ReceivedTime but I can see potential problems that would not be easy to avoid.

I process the emails in reverse order because they are accessed by position.  If email 5, say, is moved to another folder, the previous email 6 is now email 5 and the `For` loop skips it.  If emails are processed in reverse order, you do not mind that email 6 is now email 5 because you have already processed that email.

If you do not set the `NumberFormat` of the cells holding dates or amounts, they will be displayed according to Microsoft’s default for your country.  I have used my favourite display formats.  Change to your favourite.

The code does not output anything to the worksheet until the entire email has been processed and the required data extracted.  This means data from early data rows must be stored until all rows have been processed.  I have used two `Collections`: `PendingNames` and `PendingAmts`.  This is not how I would have stored the data in a macro I wrote for myself.  My problem is that alternative approaches are more complicated or require more advanced VBA.

Come back with questions about anything else you do not understand.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFromInbox()

  Const ColFixDate As Long = 1
  Const ColFixName As Long = 2
  Const ColFixAmt As Long = 3
  Const RowFixDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim AmtCrnt As Double
  Dim ColFixCrnt As Long
  Dim DateCrnt As Date
  Dim ErrorOnEmail As Boolean
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxItem As Long
  Dim InxLine As Long
  Dim InxPend As Long
  Dim Lines() As String
  Dim NameCrnt As String
  Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
  Dim olFldrIn As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olFldrOut As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olMailCrnt As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim PendingAmts As Collection
  Dim PendingNames As Collection
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim RowFixCrnt As Long
  Dim StateEmail As Long
  Dim TempStg As String
  Dim WshtFix As Worksheet

  Set WshtFix = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fixings")
  With WshtFix
    RowFixCrnt = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColFixDate).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  End With

  Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set olFldrIn = olApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("impMail")
  Set olFldrOut = olFldrIn.Folders("Processed")

  For InxItem = olFldrIn.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

    If olFldrIn.Items(InxItem).Class = Outlook.olMail Then

      Set olMailCrnt = olFldrIn.Items(InxItem)

      If InStr(olMailCrnt.Subject, "SubjectoftheEmail") > 0 Then
        Lines = Split(olMailCrnt.Body, vbCr & vbLf)

        'For InxLine = 0 To UBound(Lines)
        '  Debug.Print InxLine + 1 & "  " & Lines(InxLine)
        'Next

        StateEmail = 0    ' Before "please add ..." line
        ErrorOnEmail = False
        Set PendingAmts = Nothing
        Set PendingNames = Nothing
        Set PendingAmts = New Collection
        Set PendingNames = New Collection

        For InxLine = 0 To UBound(Lines)
          NameCrnt = ""     ' Line is not a data line
          Lines(InxLine) = Trim(Lines(InxLine))  ' Remove any leading or trailing spaces

          ' Extract data from line
          If Lines(InxLine) <> "" Then
            If StateEmail = 0 Then
              If InStr(1, Lines(InxLine), "please add the ") = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Error with email received " & olMailCrnt.ReceivedTime & vbLf & _
                            "  The first non-blank line is" & vbLf & _
                            "    " & Lines(InxLine) & vbLf & _
                            "  but I was expecting something like:" & vbLf & _
                            "    @ABC4: please add the following detail in system (for 13-Jan-2019):"
                ErrorOnEmail = True
                Exit For
              End If
              TempStg = Left$(Right$(Lines(InxLine), 13), 11)
              If Not IsDate(TempStg) Then
                Debug.Print "Error with email received " & olMailCrnt.ReceivedTime & vbLf & _
                            "  The value I extracted from the ""please add the ...""" & _
                            " line is """ & vbLf & "  " & TempStg & _
                            """ which I do not recognise as a date"
                ErrorOnEmail = True
                Exit For
              End If
              DateCrnt = CDate(TempStg)
              StateEmail = 1    ' After "please add ..." line
            ElseIf StateEmail = 1 Then
              If Lines(InxLine) = "" Then
                ' Ignore blank line
              ElseIf Lines(InxLine) = "thanks" Then
                ' No more data lines
                Exit For
              Else
                Pos = InStr(1, Lines(InxLine), " --- ")
                If Pos = 0 Then
                  Debug.Print "Error with email received " & olMailCrnt.ReceivedTime & vbLf & _
                              "  Data line: " & Lines(InxLine) & vbLf & _
                              "    does not contain ""---"" as required"
                  ErrorOnEmail = True
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  Exit For
                End If
                NameCrnt = Mid$(Lines(InxLine), 1, Pos - 1)
                TempStg = Mid$(Lines(InxLine), Pos + 5)
                If Not IsNumeric(TempStg) Then
                  Debug.Print "Error with email received " & olMailCrnt.ReceivedTime & vbLf & _
                              "  Data line:" & Lines(InxLine) & vbLf & _
                              "    value after ""---"" is not an amount"
                  ErrorOnEmail = True
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  Exit For
                End If
                AmtCrnt = CDbl(TempStg)
              End If
            End If  ' StateEmail
          End If ' Lines(InxLine) <> ""

          If ErrorOnEmail Then
            ' Ignore any remaining lines
            Exit For
          End If

          If NameCrnt <> "" Then
            ' Line was a data line without errors. Save until know entire email is error free
            PendingNames.Add NameCrnt
            PendingAmts.Add AmtCrnt
          End If

        Next InxLine

        If Not ErrorOnEmail Then
          ' Output pending rows now know entire email is error-free
          With WshtFix
            For InxPend = 1 To PendingNames.Count
              With .Cells(RowFixCrnt, ColFixDate)
                .Value = DateCrnt
                .NumberFormat = "d mmm yy"
              End With
              .Cells(RowFixCrnt, ColFixName).Value = PendingNames(InxPend)
              With .Cells(RowFixCrnt, ColFixAmt)
                .Value = PendingAmts(InxPend)
                .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
              End With
              RowFixCrnt = RowFixCrnt + 1
            Next
          End With
          ' Move fully processed email to folder Processed
          olMailCrnt.Move olFldrOut
        End If

      End If  ' InStr(olMailCrnt.Subject, "SubjectoftheEmail") > 0
    End If  ' olFldrIn.Items(InxItem).Class = Outlook.olMail

  Next InxItem

  Set olFldrIn = Nothing
  Set olFldrOut = Nothing
  olApp.Quit
  Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help, its really helped me alot. But i have a small issue the amount in output its priting withoud dot for example for me its printing 26453215278 instead 264532154.78?

Comment: Strange. I suggest clicking on the statement `Debug.Print "Date="& DateCrnt & ...` and then clicking F9.  The statement should turn brown to indicate it is now a breakpoint.  Run the routine which will stop at the breakpoint statement.  Hover over any use of `AmtCrnt`.  A tiny pop-up window should appear containing `AmtCrnt = 264532154.78`.  If the display is correct, you have a print problem. If the display is incorrect, you have an assignment problem.  That would tell us where to look for trouble.

Comment: If you had declared `AmtCrnt` as Long, you would get `AmtCrnt = 264532155` because the interpreter would round `264532154.78` to get an integer. Other than that, I do not know how to suppress the dot.

Comment: I noticed that Muhammad Ali's answer suggested Regex but I did not notice that you had included  `regex` as a tag.  Did you want a Regex solution?  I am not a Regex expert and co-incidentally I asked a Regex question yesterday and included my test harness in my question.  You might find it interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54181145/973283.

Comment: Thanks Tony Dallimore Unfortunately, the AmtCrnt = 264532154.78 in tiny pop-up window is also appearing as follows 26453215478.

Comment: @S.Haider  This tells us the problem is with the assignment of the string to AmtCrnt which is very strange. `AmtCrnt = Mid$(Lines(InxL), Pos + 5)` extracts everything following " --- ". There is no obvious way for it to extract the digits but not the dot.  Add `Debug.Print Lines(inxL)` after `AmtCrnt = ...)`.  This will output the entire line so we can see if there is anything unusual. If that doesn't show anything, I will post a routine to display the line in hexadecimal which might reveal something.

Comment: yes it gives us the entire line which exactly what we need but when we Debug.print AmtCrnt it gives us value without dot. Another question is to print them in excel workbook. I am trying to do as well but little bit confuse

Comment: @S.Haider  I do not understand how the dot is being lost.  `Mid$(Lines(InxL), Pos + 5)` is extracting a string.  `AmtCrnt = string` where `AmtCrnt` is a `Double` will convert the string to a floating-point number if possible. The effect you are describing is as though the extracted string is being multiplied by 100.

Comment: @S.Haider  I can add a section on outputting to a worksheet but I need to know how you want the worksheet arranged. The most obvious arrangements are: (1) one worksheet row per email row like my output to the Immediate Window and (2) one worksheet row per email with each amount in a column headed by the name.  Are either of these what you seek or do you have something else in mind.

Comment: @ Tony DalIimore i  will arrange the worksheet as per second arrangement with each amount in a column headed by the name.

Comment: @S.Haider  Are these two lines an example or are there more?  (I assume the names are fake.)  Are the lines always in the same order?  Are all lines always present?  Will all names in an email be known in advance?  You should answer these questions by updating your question to give a full explanation of an email's contents.  Please update your question with your latest code.  The code will need to extract the amount from each line and we need to understand what is causing the dot to be lost.

Comment: These are the only lines in the text which we need to copy, yes the names are fake. Yes the lines are always in the same order. Yes all lines are always present. Yes we do know about all names in email in advance. This is my latest code but its not working perfectly:))

Comment: @S.Haider  I do not know if you are warned that an answer has been edited so this comment is to ensure you know that I have added a section showing how to add this data to a worksheet.

Comment: @S.Haider I have only just seen your last comment which is an updated version of one you wrote yesterday in which you said there are only two data line. You now say "These are the only lines in the text which we need to copy".  This implies there are more data lines which should be skipped. The current code checks names against column headings and, if it is does not find a heading, rejects the entire email. It would be an easy change to discard the amount if the name is not found. Have a go at making this change. I will help if necessary but I think it would help you if you made the change.

Comment: thanks for your effort for new solution. First of all sorry for mis understanding. In 99 percent emails we received the format is same only one email is different. I am also sorry i could not explain you well. Daily we receive around five emails with different subjects and body remains same but name of instrument changes and amount changes.

Comment: so what i want in first column A who have header Date and Columns B has heading Instrument name and Column C has header Amount. So according to our data in column A2 we could print date, in column B2  1st instruments name, and in B3 Second Instrument name, then respectivley C2 and C3 amount of the instruments. What i am looking for next email it should print in next two rowns and respectively. In latest code ist debugging is at ´Set olFldrOut = olFldrIn.Folders("Processed")´.

Comment: I recommend you move fully processed emails to another folder so they do not get processed again.  The alternative is to delete them.  I created a Folder named "Processed" under "Inbox".  If you like this idea, you will also need to create a folder named "Processed".  Alternatively, you could move fully processed emails to some other existing folder or a folder of a different name..

Comment: Nine comments up I offered two possible arrangement for the worksheet.  You selected arrangement 2.  Are you now saying you would have preferred arrangement 1?

Comment: you are right, yes arrangement 1 is preferable i am so sorry for mis understanding.

Comment: I don't know why code is not working. code is running but no output at all. This is the second part of my project which is attached here. Would be happy if you will help in this part as well.https://stackoverflow.com/q/54293407/10512886

Comment: @S.Haider  Are there any error messages in the Immediate Window.  The code checks each email is as expected and outputs error messages if it is not as expected.  If there are no error messages, is the routine finding any emails to process? Does folder "impMail" contain any emails?  I assume "SubjectoftheEmail" is a fake subject, have you corrected it?

Comment: I have briefly looked at your other question.  I prefer to answer one question at a time.  I would like to get the problem behind this question fixed before starting something new.

Comment: thanks alot for your support. I just finished the other task now i am back i wanted to learn the whole code you wrote. I will come with questions soon.

Comment: in the immediate window print only (Error with email received 21.01.2019 12:37:59
  The first non-blank line is
    Hi,
  but I was expecting something like:
    (at)ABC4: please add the following detail in system (for 13-Jan-2019):) nothing else

Comment: @S.Haider You have changed the specification of the email. In the previous version of your question, the first non-blank line was '@ABC4: ...'. You have now added 'This EMAIL ...' and 'Hi'.  The error message: 'The first non-blank line is "Hi" ...' means that email did not have the 'This EMAIL ...' line.  Clearly, the introduction to these emails varies. You could try ignoring all lines until the '@ABC4: ...' is found.

Comment: Is the '@ABC4: ...' line always the same?  Are the body lines always the same?  It appears these emails are created by a human.  That means you will have to be prepared for changes and errors.  Have you been saving these emails?  If you have, I might be able to help identify how much they vary.

Comment: yes this line is always the same just changes with dates and rest of lines are also same. I am saving these emails too. These emails only vary with their names and values. But i got another solution as well. This issue is already solved i used this soulution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a72e14f7-5453-49f2-bdd8-bf228c557c00/how-to-copy-specific-text-from-the-body-of-the-email?forum=isvvba as well. Now i can download the data with the other approach which is linked here next step is to put this data into database system.

Comment: I am very thankful for your effort i think  we should move forward  to think about

Comment: @S.Haider.  I use Regex and for some problems it provides a very convenient solution.  I wish you good luck because I am not sure it is the right solution when the input may vary as much as these emails do.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a date in the first line, then you can get that with something simple like this:
[0-9]{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}

Try this out on regex101, to see what individual parts of the regex do

For the other part, I guess the simplest way is to read the entire line