# Can extract each occurrence of a group individually but not as a repeating group

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have many files with version numbers as the last part of the name. For example:

```
Xxxxx V2.txt
Xxxxx V2.3.txt
Xxxxx V2.10.txt
Xxxxx V2.10.3.txt
```

I use Regex to extract the parts of the version number so I can correctly sequence the files † and so I can calculate the next version number ‡.

† For example: V2.2 comes before V2.10 and V2.2 comes before V2.2.3.

‡ For example: the next version after V2.9 is V2.10.

I can process each style of version number individually but I cannot generalise to create one Regex pattern for all styles.

```
Text               Pattern                          Value(s) extracted
Xxxxx V2.txt       Xxxxx V(\d+)\.txt                2
Xxxxx V2.3.txt     Xxxxx V(\d+)\.(\d+)\.txt         2  3
Xxxxx V2.10.3.txt  Xxxxx V(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.txt  2  10  3
Xxxxx V2.10.3.txt  Xxxxx V(\d+){\.(\d+)}*\.txt      No match
```

I do not understand why the last pattern does not work for every style of version number.  Any guidance appreciated.

**New section in response to comments**

I was hoping there was a simple mistake in my Regex pattern and that my code was irrelevant.  I tidied up my test code to create:

```
Sub CtrlTestCapture()

  Dim Patterns As Variant
  Dim Texts As Variant

  Texts = Array("Xxxxx V12.txt", _
                "Xxxxx V12.3.txt", _
                "Xxxxx V12.4.5.txt", _
                "Xxxxx V12.4.5.3.txt")

  Patterns = Array("Xxxxx V(\d+)\.txt", _
                   "Xxxxx V(\d+)\.(\d+)\.txt", _
                   "Xxxxx V(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.txt", _
                   "Xxxxx V(\d+){\.(\d+)}+\.txt", _
                   "Xxxxx V(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.txt" , _
                   "Xxxxx V(\d+)(\.(\d+))*\.txt")

  Call TestCapture(Patterns, Texts)

End Sub
Sub TestCapture(ByRef Patterns As Variant, ByRef Texts As Variant)

  Dim InxM As Long
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim Matches As MatchCollection
  Dim PatternCrnt As Variant
  Dim RegEx As New RegExp
  Dim SubMatchCrnt As Variant
  Dim TextCrnt As Variant

  With RegEx
    .Global = True         ' Find all matches
    .MultiLine = False     ' Match cannot extend across linebreak
    .IgnoreCase = True

    For Each PatternCrnt In Patterns
     .Pattern = PatternCrnt

      For Each TextCrnt In Texts
        Debug.Print "==========================================="
        Debug.Print "   Pattern: """ & PatternCrnt & """"
        Debug.Print "      Text: """ & TextCrnt & """"
        If Not .test(TextCrnt) Then
          Debug.Print Space(12) & "Text does not match pattern"
        Else
          Set Matches = .Execute(TextCrnt)
          If Matches.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print Space(12) & "Match but no captures"
          Else
            For InxM = 0 To Matches.Count - 1
              Debug.Print "-------------------------------------------"
              With Matches(InxM)
                Debug.Print "     Match: " & InxM + 1
                Debug.Print "     Value: """ & .Value & """"
                Debug.Print "    Length: " & .Length
                Debug.Print "FirstIndex: " & .FirstIndex
                For InxS = 0 To .SubMatches.Count - 1
                  Debug.Print "  SubMatch: " & InxS + 1 & " """ & .SubMatches(InxS) & """"
                Next
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End If
      Next
    Next
    Debug.Print "==========================================="

  End With

End Sub
```

With this code, the Wiktor Stribiżew regex pattern produced better results than with my untidy code.  I will have to review my original code to locate my mistake.  With this code, the output for the Wiktor Stribiżew regex pattern is:

```
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.txt"
    Length: 13
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 ""
  SubMatch: 3 ""
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.3.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.3.txt"
    Length: 15
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 "3"
  SubMatch: 3 ""
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.txt"
    Length: 17
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 "4"
  SubMatch: 3 "5"
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.3.txt"
            Text does not match pattern
===========================================
```

This has a fixed number of captures rather than the variable number I was attempting.  I will also have to work out how to extend it to process “12.4.5.3” which is the most complicated version number style I have ever seen.  This is not perfect but it is definitely an improvement on my current workaround.  You are using Regex characters I do not recognise so I will need to study this carefully.

With the above code, the Tiw regex pattern produced this output:

```
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(\.(\d+))*\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.txt"
    Length: 13
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 ""
  SubMatch: 3 ""
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(\.(\d+))*\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.3.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.3.txt"
    Length: 15
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 ".3"
  SubMatch: 3 "3"
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(\.(\d+))*\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.txt"
    Length: 17
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 ".5"
  SubMatch: 3 "5"
===========================================
   Pattern: "Xxxxx V(\d+)(\.(\d+))*\.txt"
      Text: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.3.txt"
-------------------------------------------
     Match: 1
     Value: "Xxxxx V12.4.5.3.txt"
    Length: 19
FirstIndex: 0
  SubMatch: 1 "12"
  SubMatch: 2 ".3"
  SubMatch: 3 "3"
===========================================
```

That is, it always seems to capture: the first part, the last part including the dot and the last part without the dot.  Promising but not quite there.

**Part 3**

I had overlooked the request for a clear explanation of the result I seek.

I use version numbers on all my important files.  I receive file from others that include version numbers some of which are a lot more complicated than mine.  I always have the version number as the last part of the filename and I always have a “V” before the version number.  If I receive files that do not conform to my format, I rename them so they do.  So I have files with names like:

- Xxxxx VN.xxx
- Xxxxx VN.N.xxx
- Xxxxx VN.N.N.xxx
- Xxxxx VN.N.N.N.xxx

I wish to extract the Ns to a variable length array or a collection so I can process them using general-purpose routines.  In fact, I already have those general-purpose routines.  These routines rely on some messy VBA code that extracts the Ns.  I thought using Regex would allow me to tidy up my code.

Comment: If you expect one to three parts, use `V(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?\.txt`. In VBA regex, you cannot access all captures of a group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks for the suggestion but it does not work for me.  It returns one match per character of the text will every match being the empty string.

Comment: You have not shown your code, nor have you explained what exact output you want to get. If you want something to work for you, you need to provide more details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I have tidied up my test code and your pattern now gives much better results.  Please see new section to my question.

Comment: There was a suggestion from Tiv which seems to have disappeared.  The new section in my question demonstrates the output from that suggested pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I missed "nor have you explained what exact output you want to get".  I have now added this explanation to the end of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
V(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\.txt$
```

The required version is captured in Group 1. You can further split the contents of Group 1 with a `.`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lnBjej/1)**

**Code:**

```
Dim objReg, strFile, objMatches, strVersion, arrVersion
strFile = "Xxxxx V2.3.txt"
Set objReg = New RegExp
objReg.Global = True
objReg.Multiline = True
objReg.Pattern = "V(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\.txt$"

If objReg.Test(strFile) Then
    Set objMatches = objReg.Execute(strFile)
    strVersion =  objMatches.item(0).submatches.item(0)   'To get the full version number
    arrVersion = Split(strVersion,".")                    'To get each number in the version(stored in array)
End If
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `V(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\.txt$`
- `V` - matches `V`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit. After matching as many digits as possible, match 0 or more occurrences of a dot `.` followed by 1+ digits. This whole match is captured in Group 1 and is your required version number
- `\.txt` - matches `.txt`
- `$` - asserts the end of the line.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  I am trying to respond properly to each comment and answer in sequence.  This is the first suggestion I have found that works.  It extracts the entire version number as a single string which I can easily divide with `Split`.  I was thinking of capturing each part of the version number separately but capturing the entire version number is probably more convenient.  +1 for a working answer.  I will accept once I have checked all the other suggestions.

Comment: The other suggestions have been deleted so you have no rival.  This is not the answer I was seeking but is better that the answer I was seeking.  I remember when I was in Support, I would get questions about some obscure technology.  After much questioning I would discover their actual requirement was quite simple but they had decided that the obscure technology was the solution.

Comment: Glad that the solution helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex solution if you'd prefer. You can convert the version number, to a number, then sort it.

```
Sub GetOrderedList()
    Dim Texts               As Variant
    Dim FileName            As String
    Dim FileArrayList       As Object
    Dim Item                As Variant

    Set FileArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Texts = Array("Xxxxx V12.txt", _
                  "Xxxxx V12.3.txt", _
                  "Xxxxx V12.4.5.txt", _
                  "Xxxxx V12.4.5.3.txt")


    For i = LBound(Texts) To UBound(Texts)
        'You get use the FileSystemObject to make this a bit easier
        FileName = Replace(Replace(Split(Texts(i), " ")(UBound(Split(Texts(i), " "))), "V", ""), ".txt", "")
        PeriodPosition = InStr(1, FileName, ".")

        'Convert to a number, then sort
        If PeriodPosition > 0 Then FileName = Left$(FileName, PeriodPosition) & Replace(FileName, ".", "0", PeriodPosition + 1)
        FileArrayList.Add FileName
    Next

    'Sort
    FileArrayList.Sort

    'Print out, ascending order
    For Each Item In FileArrayList
        Debug.Print Item
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer which includes some interesting ideas.  It does sort `FileArrayList` correctly but that is only one of my use cases.  At the moment, I cannot see how to develop this approach to handle all my use cases.  However, +1 for the interesting ideas.