# Exporting data from outlook to excel with parsing

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I receive a form in email that looks as follows.

The submitted details are below:

```
Region Europe
Country Spain
Contactable by email no
Contactable by phone no
Title MR
First name John
Last name Doe
Email j.doe@doe.com
Contact number 1234567
Role Customer
Institution companyname ltd
Product TEST product
Message 
TEST Question
```

I need to extract some of the fields into the Excel Workbook.

I have been entering those emails manually so I need to find a code to extract data into next empty row.

My Excel headers look like this

[Excel columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEXIx.jpg)

[image]

I have checked some of the answers here and I managed to put together a code but it doesn't seem to work as needed.

Here what I have so far.

I entered it into Outlook VBA module.

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim topOlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myOlFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myOlMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set myNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("mapi")
    Set objItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Dim xlObj As worksheet
    Set xlObj = ActiveSheet                          

    Dim anchor As Range
    Set anchor = xlObj.Range("b2")                   

        anchor.Offset(0, 0).Value = "Country"          
    anchor.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Role"         
    anchor.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Product"
    anchor.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Message"
    anchor.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Sender"


    Dim msgText As String
    Dim msgLine() As String
    Dim messageArray() As String

    i = 0                                            
    For Each myOlMailItem In myOlFolder.Items
        i = i + 1                                    

        msgText = myOlMailItem.Body                  

        messageArray = Split(msgText, vbCrLf)       

        For j = 0 To UBound(messageArray)

            msgLine = Split(messageArray(j) & ":", ":")  

            Select Case Left(msgLine(0), 6)              

                Case "Countr"
                    anchor.Offset(i, 0).Value = msgLine(1)             

                Case "Role"
                    anchor.Offset(i, 1).Value = messageArray(j + 1)   

                Case "Product"
                    anchor.Offset(i, 2).Value = messageArray(j + 1)    

                Case "Message"
                    anchor.Offset(i, 3).Value = msgLine(1)             

            End Select
            anchor.Offset(i, 4).Value = myOlMailItem.SenderName
            anchor.Offset(i, -1).Value = i                             

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I would really appreciate your help and comments.

Edit:

I have run the diagnostics tool and this is how email body looks like:

```
     |Message ‹2 crlf›|
      |TEST question - please confirm receipt if received. ‹2 crlf›|
      |AAA-BBB-001366 ‹2 crlf›|
      |JAN 2020 ‹2 crlf›|
      | ‹2 crlf›|
      |info.com <http://info.com/?mc_phishing_protection_id=xxxbpg|
      |db3lse2ip1c6bc0n0>‹2 s›‹2 crlf›|
      | ‹2 crlf›|
      | ‹3 crlf›|
      |This email (including any attachment) is intended only for the use by the recipients named above and|
      | contains proprietary information that may be confidential, copyrighted and/or privileged. Unauthori|
      |zed disclosure, use or copying is prohibited. If this email was sent to you in error or if you are n|
      |ot an intended recipient, please notify the sender immediately and delete this e-mail from your syst|
      |ems. Thank you‹crlf›|
Html: |<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmln|
      |s:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omm|
      |l" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>‹2 crlf›|
      |<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">‹crlf›|
      |<title>Simple Transactional Email</title>‹crlf›|
      |<style><!--‹crlf›|
      |/* Font Definitions */‹crlf›|
      |@font-face‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{font-family:"Cambria Math";‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}‹crlf›|
      |@font-face‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{font-family:Calibri;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}‹crlf›|
      |/* Style Definitions */‹crlf›|
      |p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{margin:0cm;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›margin-bottom:.0001pt;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-size:11.0pt;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}‹crlf›|
      |a:link, span.MsoHyperlink‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-priority:99;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›color:blue;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›text-decoration:underline;}‹crlf›|
      |a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-priority:99;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›color:purple;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›text-decoration:underline;}‹crlf›|
      |p.msonormal0, li.msonormal0, div.msonormal0‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-name:msonormal;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›mso-margin-top-alt:auto;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›margin-right:0cm;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›margin-left:0cm;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-size:11.0pt;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}‹crlf›|
      |span.preheader‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-name:preheader;}‹crlf›|
      |span.EmailStyle19‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-type:personal;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›color:windowtext;}‹crlf›|
      |span.EmailStyle22‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-type:personal-reply;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›color:windowtext;}‹crlf›|
      |.MsoChpDefault‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{mso-style-type:export-only;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›font-size:10.0pt;}‹crlf›|
      |@page WordSection1‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{size:612.0pt 792.0pt;‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}‹crlf›|
      |div.WordSection1‹crlf›|
      |‹tb›{page:WordSection1;}‹crlf›|
      |--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>‹crlf›|
      |<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />‹crlf›|
      |</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>‹crlf›|
      |<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">‹crlf›|
      |<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />‹crlf›|
      |</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->‹crlf›|
      |</head>‹crlf›|
      |<body bgcolor="#F6F6F6" lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple"><pre><div style="background-color:#F|
      |FEB9C; width:100%; max-width:1040px; border-style: solid; border-color:#9C6500; border-width:1pt; pa|
      |dding:2pt; font-size:10pt; line-height:12pt; font-family:'Calibri'; color:Black; text-align: left;">|
      |<span style="color:#9C6500; font-weight:bold;">CAUTION:</span>This email originated from outside of |
      |the Vifor Pharma Group organisation. Do not click on links or open attachments unless you recognise |
      |the sender and know the content is safe.</div>‹crlf›|
      |</pre>‹crlf›|
      |<div class="WordSection1">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>‹crlf›|
      |<div>‹crlf›|
      |<div style="border:none;border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0cm 0cm 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><b>From:</b> Info GM  &lt;<a href="mailto:noreply@info|
      |.com">noreply@info.com</a>&gt;‹crlf›|
      |<br>‹crlf›|
      |<b>Sent:</b> 19 February 2020 16:20<br>‹crlf›|
      |<b>To:</b> Info1 &lt;<a href="mailto:infor1@info.com">pharma|
      |info2@info.com</a>&gt;<br>‹crlf›|
      |<b>Cc:</b> GM &lt;<a href="mailto:info@info.com">GlobalMedInfo@info|
      |.com</a>&gt;<br>‹crlf›|
      |<b>Subject:</b> New query received<o:p></o:p></p>‹crlf›|
      |</div>‹crlf›|
      |</div>‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>‹crlf›|
      |<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:1|
      |00.0%;background:#F6F6F6">‹crlf›|
      |<tbody>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">&nbsp;<|
      |o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td width="580" valign="top" style="width:435.0pt;padding:7.5pt 7.5pt 7.5pt 7.5pt">‹crlf›|
      |<div>‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span class="preheader"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&q|
      |uot;,sans-serif">New query received</span></span><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Ari|
      |al&quot;,sans-serif">‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:1|
      |00.0%;background:white;border-radius: 3px">‹crlf›|
      |<tbody>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:15.0pt 15.0pt 15.0pt 15.0pt;box-sizing: border-box">‹crlf›|
      |<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:1|
      |00.0%;box-sizing: border-box">‹crlf›|
      |<tbody>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p style="mso-margin-top-alt:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:11.25pt;margin-left:0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">New product complaint query |
      |received from info.com<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |<p style="mso-margin-top-alt:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:11.25pt;margin-left:0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">The submitted details are be|
      |low:<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:1|
      |00.0%;background:white;box-sizing: border-box">‹crlf›|
      |<tbody>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Region|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Europe|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Country|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Switzer|
      |land‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Title|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Ms|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">First n|
      |ame‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Joe|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Last na|
      |me‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Doe|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Email|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><a href|
      |="mailto:Joe.Doe.ext@info.com">Joe.Doe.ext@info.com</a>‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Contact|
      | number‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm"></td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Role|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Other|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Institu|
      |tion‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm"></td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Product|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">TEST pr|
      |oduct‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Message|
      |‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 11.25pt 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal"><i><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">TEST|
      | question - please confirm receipt if received.‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></i></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="text-align:right"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-famil|
      |y:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">ALL-ALL-001366‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |<tr>‹crlf›|
      |<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">‹crlf›|
      |<p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="text-align:right"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-famil|
      |y:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">JAN 2020‹crlf›|
      |<o:p></o:p></span></p>‹crlf›|
      |</td>‹crlf›|
      |</tr>‹crlf›|
      |</tbody>‹crlf›|
```

I have run the tool and here it the text:

`` @Tony Dallimore Here is the text `Text: |From: Info <noreply@info.com <mailto:noreply@info.com> > ‹crlf›|
      |Sent: 19 February 2020 16:20‹crlf›|
      |To: Email1 <email1@info.com <mailto:email1|
      |@info.com> >‹crlf›|
      |Cc: Infor <Info1@infor.com <mailto:infor1@info.com> >‹crlf›|
      |Subject: New query received‹2 crlf›|
      | ‹2 crlf›|
      | ‹2 crlf›|
      |New query received ‹2 crlf›|
      |New product complaint query received from info.com‹2 crlf›|
      |The submitted details are below:‹2 crlf›|
      |Region ‹2 crlf›|
      |Europe ‹2 crlf›|
      |Country ‹2 crlf›|
      |Switzerland ‹2 crlf›|
      |Title ‹2 crlf›|
      |Mr ‹2 crlf›|
      |First name ‹2 crlf›|
      |Joe ‹2 crlf›|
      |Last name ‹2 crlf›|
      |Doe ‹2 crlf›|
      |Email ‹2 crlf›|
      |joedoe@info.com <mailto:joedoe@info.com>‹2 s›‹2 crlf›|
      |Contact number ‹2 crlf›|
      |‹tb›‹crlf›|
      |Role ‹2 crlf›|
      |Other ‹2 crlf›|
      |Institution ‹2 crlf›|
      |‹tb›‹crlf›|
      |Product ‹2 crlf›|
      |TEST product ‹2 crlf›|
      |Message ‹2 crlf›|
      |TEST question - please confirm receipt if received. ‹2 crlf›|
      |AAA-BBB-001366 ‹2 crlf›|
      |JAN 2020 ‹2 crlf›|
      | ‹2 crlf›| ``

Comment: What is not working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What is the purpose of `msgLine = Split(messageArray(j) & ":", ":")`?

Comment: When I run this macro I get a message Compile error: USer-defined type not defined. `msgLine = Split(messageArray(j) & ":", ":")` was supposed to split the lines

Comment: `messageArray = Split(msgText, vbCrLf)` splits an email's body into lines.  If a line contained a colon (for example, "Region: Europe") then `msgLine = Split(messageArray(j), ":")` would split the line into keyword and value.  What do you think ` & ":"` does with the example lines?

Comment: Have a look at this question and my answer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54178058/973283.  The OP wanted an Excel macro which extracted selected values from selected emails and added them to the bottom of a worksheet.  The extraction process is very different to yours but the overall structure will be similar.

Comment: I have checked the above thread and I tried implement it in my case to no avail. Therefore I decided to go step by step to try to write a code that I need. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `Option Explicit` to the top of your code.  This is very helpful in finding compile-time errors.

```
Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Set objItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

You declare `myOlApp` but you use `objApp` without initialising it.

```
Dim myOlMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set objItem = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

You declare `myOlMailItem` but you use `objItem`.

```
i = 0
For j = 0 To UBound(messageArray)
```

You do not declare `i` or `j`.  If you omit `Option Explicit`, you do not have to declare every variable because they will be declared for you as type Variant.  However, this means every minor spelling mistake becomes a new variable.  For example:

```
Count = Conut +1
```

`Conut` will be declared as a new variable and initialised to zero.

---

I do not get “User-defined type not defined”.  Thinking about this made me realise I had made a false assumption about where this code is placed.

You write, for example, `Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace` and `Dim anchor As Range`.

You can write VBA within Outlook to access an Excel worksheet or you can write VBA within Excel to access an Outlook folder.  If you are within Outlook, you must tell the Outlook VBA compiler that you want to access Excel.  And vice versa.  You prefix `NameSpace` but you do not prefix `Range`.  I assumed this code was within an Excel workbook.  But on reflection, I now believe this code is within Outlook.  On rereading your question, I see that you say it is Outlook VBA; I missed that on my first reading.

It does not really matter where this code is placed; it cannot work.  If you are within Outlook, you cannot reference the active worksheet without opening an Excel workbook first.  If you are within Excel, which email has the user selected?

Let us step back from the code and consider your design options.

Using `ActiveExplorer` is my favourite method of testing a new email processing macro.  I can select a simple email for my first test.  I can correct the macro and rerun it against the same email as often as I wish.  Once the macro works on simple emails, I can try it on more complicated ones.  However, once my new macro is working properly, I want to automate the selection.  I do not want to think: “It is 12:00, have any of these emails arrived this morning?  If so, I need to go into to Outlook, find any that have arrived and process them.”  I want to think: “It is 12:00, have any new emails been copied to my Excel workbook.”

There are four distinct methods of selecting an email for processing.  You cannot mix and match.  These methods are:

1. User selection which is the method you are trying.
2. You can read down a folder (Oldest to Newest) or up a folder (Newest to Oldest) or you can sort the folder by any of the regular properties.
3. You can create a Rule which tells Outlook to monitor Inbox for particular emails and do something when one arrives.
4. You can use events to tell Outlook to call a macro whenever a new email is placed in a particular folder.

With method 1, it is the user that identifies an email to be processed.  With the other methods, there must be a test a macro can perform.  Are these emails all from the same sender?  Do these emails have a particular subject or a particular phrase in the subject?  Failing a simple check, you can look in the body for “Region”, “Country” and “Contactable by”.

A problem with methods 3 and 4, is that the macro is called when one of these emails arrive.  The macro must quickly open the workbook, update it and close it.  What is to happen if an email arrives while the workbook is being processed by a user?  I would not want to tackle this issue if I was new to VBA as you are.

I would use method 2.  I would have an Excel workbook that contained a macro that accessed Outlook’s Inbox and looked through the newest emails for any of the target emails.  This is not quite what I said I wanted but it is close enough.  Every time I open the workbook, I can, if I wish, run the macro to process any new emails.  This should only take a few seconds if the macro is run regularly.

It might be worth using a rule to move these emails to a dedicated folder.  This would mean that the macro does not have to search through Inbox for these emails.  This may look as though I am mixing methods 2 and 3 but not in the same macro.  Whenever, you open Outlook new emails arrive from the server and the rule will move any target emails to their folder.  When you open the workbook, you can decide to check for new target emails or review those emails already recorded in the workbook.

I think that is enough for you to think about for the moment.  Review the approaches I have discussed and come to some decisions about what you want.

**Part 2**

I have not had the free time I expected this evening so I doubt I will finish today.  I also have the problem that I should have asked more questions about your requirement.

To give you something to look at tomorrow, I have produced a demo macro which includes a lot of what you need to know and which I think you will find helpful in understanding the final macro.

I have created a workbook and worksheet with a heading that matches that shown in your question.  I have named the workbook “Email Data.xlsx” and have placed it on my desktop.  I have named the worksheet “Email Data”.  I assume you have different names and a different location.  The macro tells you what to change.

An Outlook macro that wants to access an Excel workbook, must have access to the Excel library.  You might know how to add references but just in case:

1. Open Outlook VBA Editor.
2. Click [Tools] in the Standard Toolbar then [References…].
3. A list of Available References is displayed.  Some available references at the top (such as Visual Basic for Application) are ticked.  Most references are not ticked.
4. If “Microsoft Excel nn.n Object Library” is ticked, click [Cancel] because there is nothing to do.  Note: the value of “nn.n” depends on the version of Outlook and Excel you are using.  This code should work with any version of Excel, so it does not matter if you are using an old version.
5. If “Microsoft Excel nn.n Object Library” is not ticked, scroll down the list until you find this reference and click the box n the left to tick it.
6. Click [OK].
7. Repeat step 2 and check that “Microsoft Excel nn.n Object Library” now appears at the top of the list and is ticked.

Copy this macro to an Outlook module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DemoOpenWorkbook()

  ' Needs reference to Microsoft Excel n.nn Object Library
  ' where n.nn depends on the version of Office being used

  Dim Path As String
  Dim WbkEmailData As Excel.Workbook
  Dim WshtEmailData As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim XlApp As New Excel.Application

  ' Replace with path to the folder which holds your workbook
  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

  With XlApp
    .Visible = True   ' Slows your application but makes debugging easier
    ' Replace "Email Data.xlsx" with the name of your workbook
    Set WbkEmailData = .Workbooks.Open(Path & "\Email Data.xlsx")
  End With

  With WbkEmailData
    ' Replace "Email Data" with the name of your worksheet
    Set WshtEmailData = .Worksheets("Email Data")
  End With

  With WshtEmailData
    Debug.Print .Cells(1, 1).Value
    Debug.Print .Cells(1, 2).Value
    Debug.Print .Cells(1, 3).Value
  End With

  WbkEmailData.Close
  Set WshtEmailData = Nothing
  Set WbkEmailData = Nothing
  XlApp.Quit
  Set XlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Make the changes I have discussed above.  Run the macro.  The workbook is opened, the first three headings from the worksheet are output to the Immediate Window and the Workbook is closed.  The Immediate Window will now contain:

```
DATE OF RECEIPT
DELIVERY DATE
MONTH
```

Work down my code.  If you do not understand any of my statements, look them up.  In general, typing something like “Outlook VBA Name-of-statement-you-do-not-understand” into your favourite search engine will find an explanation.  If necessary, come back with questions but I hope you can understand why this code works without any more help from me.

Note: you do not need to remember this code.  There are VBA statements and blocks of VBA code that I type often enough to remember them.  But I am not ashamed to look up something I use infrequently or to look back at a working macro that does something similar to what I want to do today.

**Part3**

The next two macros demonstrate my favourite technique for testing a new email processing macro.  Near the bottom of `TestNewEmailProcessingMacro`, you will find the statement `Call EmailProcessingMacro(ItemCrnt)`.  When I create a new email processing macro, I amend this statement to call my new macro.  I then select a simple email of the type my macro processes before running `TestNewEmailProcessingMacro()`.  I carefully check my macro processes the simple email correctly.  If not, I can correct the macro and rerun the test as often as necessary.  Once my macro processes a simple email correctly, I can try more complicated emails.  I continue until my macro performs to my entire satisfaction.  I would then call my new macro from a loop, a rule or an event as explained in the first part of my answer.

```
Sub TestNewEmailProcessingMacro()

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      If ItemCrnt.Class = olMail Then
        Call EmailProcessingMacro(ItemCrnt)
      End If
    Next
  End If

End Sub
Public Sub EmailProcessingMacro(ByRef ItemCrnt As MailItem)

  With ItemCrnt
    Debug.Print .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject
  End With

End Sub
```

The above code shows how to use Explorer correctly.  In your code you have `Set objItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)`.  This attempts to access the first selected email even if none are selected and ignores any further emails that have been selected.

I will next show you how to combine the techniques shown in the above macros.

**Part 4**

Below are the two macros which together do what I think you want.

You will need to make the same changes that were necessary with `DemoOpenWorkbook()`.  That is, you will have to change the path, the name of the workbook and the name of the worksheet.  You will not need to add another reference to the Excel library, once is enough.

Select one or more of these emails and then run macro `CtrlCopyEmailDataToExcel()`.  This is the macro which opens the workbook and then saves the changes.  This macro calls `CopyEmailDataToExcel()` for every selected email.  This is the macro which decodes the email’s body and extracts the four values from it and copies them to the worksheet.  It also extracts the required properties from the email and copies them to the workbook.  I have documented all my assumptions about the email and the worksheet in the macro.  Make a copy of your workbook in case my assumptions are incorrect, and the macro damages the workbook.  However, I am hopeful that the macros will meet your requirement.

I hope I have explained the principles behind my code so you understand what is happening and can create your own macros to perform similar copying of data from emails to Excel.

```
Sub CtrlCopyEmailDataToExcel()

  ' Extracts data from selected emails and copies it to Excel

  ' Needs reference to Microsoft Excel n.nn Object Library
  ' where n.nn depends on the version of Office being used

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim Path As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim WbkEmailData As Excel.Workbook
  Dim WshtEmailData As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim XlApp As New Excel.Application

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else

    ' Replace with path to the folder which holds your
    Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

    With XlApp
      .Visible = True   ' Slows your application but makes debugging easier
      ' Replace "Email Data.xlsx" with the name of your workbook
      Set WbkEmailData = .Workbooks.Open(Path & "\Email Data.xlsx")
    End With

    With WbkEmailData
      ' Replace "Email Data" with the name of your worksheet
      Set WshtEmailData = .Worksheets("Email Data")
    End With

    With WshtEmailData
      ' If the cursor is placed in the bottom cell of column A and Up Arrow
      ' clicked, the cursor will be move up to the last row with data in
      ' column A.  This is the VBA equivalent.  Adding 1 means RowCrnt will
      ' become the number of the first unused row.  This relies on every
      ' used row having a value column A. Replace "A" if another column is
      ' a better choice.  If no column is guaranteed to not contain blank
      ' cell, I can provide a routine that finds the last used row in a
      ' different way.
      RowCrnt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Call CopyEmailDataToExcel(ItemCrnt, WshtEmailData, RowCrnt)
    Next
  End If

  WbkEmailData.Close SaveChanges:=True
  Set WshtEmailData = Nothing
  Set WbkEmailData = Nothing
  XlApp.Quit
  Set XlApp = Nothing

End Sub
Sub CopyEmailDataToExcel(ByRef ItemCrnt As MailItem, _
                         ByRef WshtEmailData As Worksheet, _
                         ByRef RowCrnt As Long)

  ' The Body of ItemCrnt is the HtmlBody with all the Html tags stripped out.

  ' Most the HtmlBody was a table with two cells per row.  The left-hand cell
  ' would be a keyword such as "Country", "Role" or "Product" while the
  ' right-hand cell would be the value associated with the keyword. The nature
  ' of the HtmBody and the nature of the conversion to text means a table row
  ' would become, for example: Country CR LF CR LF France CR LF CR LF

  ' The bottom of the table had only one cell per row. This is achieved with a
  ' "ColSpan = 2" attribute in the first and only <td> of the row.  The change
  ' of style starts with a cell containing "Message". These final rows are:
  ' Message CR LF CR LF Line1 CR LF CR LF Line2 CR LF CR LF ...
  ' The last two lines of this block are not required.

  ' The start of Body did not come from the same Html table and the format is
  ' slightly different.  However, the start of Body contains nothing of
  ' interest.

  ' Two properties of ItemCrnt are to be copied to the worksheet: SentOn (Date
  ' email sent) and SenderName.

  ' The month of property Sent On is required for another column.

  ' This routine copies the seven values from ItemCrnt to RowCrnt of the
  ' worksheet and then steps RowCrnt ready for the next row.

  Const ColReceived As Long = 1
  Const ColSentOn As Long = 2    ' Delivery Date
  Const ColMonth As Long = 3
  Const ColCountry As Long = 4
  Const ColEnqType As Long = 6   ' Role
  Const ColProduct As Long = 7
  Const ColMessage As Long = 8   ' Question

  Dim BodyLines() As String
  Dim InxL As Long
  Dim Key As String
  Dim LenKey As Long
  Dim Message As String
  Dim MessageFound As Boolean
  Dim Ub As Long

  ' At the start of ItemCrnt.Body, the lines are separated by single CRLFs.
  ' However, the start of ItemCrnt.Body contains nothing of interest so it
  ' does not matter that it is not split correctly.
  BodyLines = Split(ItemCrnt.Body, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

  ' Ignore any trailing blank lines
  For Ub = UBound(BodyLines) To LBound(BodyLines) Step -1
    If BodyLines(Ub) <> "" Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  With WshtEmailData

    MessageFound = False
    InxL = LBound(BodyLines)
    Do While InxL <= Ub

      If InStr(1, BodyLines(InxL), "Country") <> 0 Then
        ' The country is the next row
        InxL = InxL + 1
        .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCountry).Value = BodyLines(InxL)
      ElseIf InStr(1, BodyLines(InxL), "Role") <> 0 Then
        ' The role is the next row
        InxL = InxL + 1
        .Cells(RowCrnt, ColEnqType).Value = BodyLines(InxL)
      ElseIf InStr(1, BodyLines(InxL), "Product") <> 0 Then
        ' The product is the next row
        InxL = InxL + 1
        .Cells(RowCrnt, ColProduct).Value = BodyLines(InxL)
      ElseIf InStr(1, BodyLines(InxL), "Message") <> 0 Then
         ' The message starts in the next row
       InxL = InxL + 1
        MessageFound = True
        Exit Do
      End If

      InxL = InxL + 1
    Loop

    If MessageFound Then

      'Build message as Line1 vbLF Line2 vbLF Line3 and so on
      Message = BodyLines(InxL)
      For InxL = InxL + 1 To Ub
        If BodyLines(InxL) = "AAA-BBB-001366" Then
          Exit For
        End If
        Message = Message & vbLf & BodyLines(InxL)
      Next

      With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColMessage)
        .Value = Message
        .WrapText = True
      End With
    End If

    With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColReceived)
      .Value = ItemCrnt.ReceivedTime
      .NumberFormat = "dmmmyy"
    End With

    With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColSentOn)
      .Value = ItemCrnt.SentOn
      .NumberFormat = "dmmmyy"
    End With

    With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColMonth)
      .Value = ItemCrnt.ReceivedTime
      .NumberFormat = "mmm"
    End With

  End With

  RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I really appreciate your help. I will have a look at my code, read your comments again and come back with hopefully better structured code.

Comment: Having thought about my scenario I came to conclusion that I need an outlook macro as some of the emails that are received are not entered into the excel worksheet as they are spam or are irrelevant. Therefore I would prefer to select an email, read it, if needed click macro and then move it to a different folder.

Comment: @CatBehemoth  Sorry, I am busy with someone else's problem.  I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: @CatBehemoth  In your example, you have line such as "Region Europe".  This is a possible format but a more usual format would be "Region: Europe".  Your code includes a statement that appears to be trying to split lines on colon.  Please confirm the format of your lines.

Comment: The format of my line does not have colon. It is just word Europe and then the value after that can be different (America, Asia etc.)

Comment: I have now added parts 2 and 3 of answer and am working on part 4.

Comment: Ok. So I have amended the code and run it in outlook. It opened the excel and closed it but no changes were made in it. Please advise.

Comment: Macro `DemoOpenWorkbook()` opens the workbook, displays some values from it and closes the workbook.  It does not change the workbook.  The objective was to show how to open and close a workbook from Outlook.  The display was just to prove the workbook had been opened.  I have now finished testing the macros that copies data from the emails to the workbook.  Once I have written the explanatory text, I will post the macros.

Comment: Dear Tony, thank you for your help. I did adjust the code to my needs and I managed to get some columns but some are still missing. I think it may be because there is a space and a tab between the Country and name of the country. I tried to add more space but it doesn't work. Also when i parsed the message part it also captured the footer of the email. I was looking to find a way to put a command to capture the verbatim between message and the footer but can't get round to it. My last question is what shall I change to keep the excel open so I can check if all parsed correctly. Again, thanks!

Comment: If you suspect the email body is not as you thought, you need to use a diagnostic macro of mine which outputs the body (and other properties) to a text file with control characters replaced by {cr}, {lf} and {tb} so you can see exactly what you are trying to decode.  You can find the macro at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283.  If you cannot work out how to decode the body, I suggest you add the output from the macro to your question so I and others can have a look.

Comment: @CatBehemoth.  Need the bottom of `CtrlCopyEmailDataToExcel()`, you will find: `WbkEmailData.Close SaveChanges:=True`.  This is the statement that saves the Excel workbook.  Delete this statement to leave the workbook open.  The statement `.Visible = True` near the beginning means the workbook will be visible.

Comment: Dear Tony, now I see how your diagnostic tool works. Amazing! This what I get when I use it:

Comment: @CatBehemoth  You have added the Html body to your question.  It will be easier to extract from the text body.  Please include the block labelled "Text" which will be much smaller.

Comment: @CatBehemoth. It would be possible to extract from the Html body but not easy. The fifth row is `|‹7 s›<tr>‹crlf›|`.  The `<tr>` is the start of a table row.  The next row contains `<td … >` which is the start of a table cell.  Three rows down is `Product` which is the cell contents.  Two rows down is `</td>` which is the end of the table cell.  Everything else is white space or formatting.  Continuing down you will find another `<td … >` then `TEST` then `</td>` and on the next row `</tr>` which end the row.  ...

Comment: ...  If you discard all the whitespace and the formatting, you have a row with two cells containing `Product` and `TEST`.   The text body will have no formatting and will probably have `Product` and `TEST` on separate lines.  If you study the Text body, you should be able to see why it will be easier to process.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have tried to find block "Text" but to no avail. Please advise. In addition, would you recommend any website, book, course which would help me to understand VBA better?

Comment: There are no shortage of online tutorials for Excel VBA but I have never tried any of them. I doubt they were available when I started learning VBA in 2002. I prefer books anyway  I went to a good library and had a quick look at all their Excel VBA primers.  I borrowed the ones I liked best and tried them out at home. I then bought the one I liked best. I am reluctant to recommend the one I liked best. It matched my learning style which will probably be different from yours  I learnt my first programming language in 1965. I had already used BASIC when I started I started with VBA.

Comment: @CatBehemoth   With my background, the books I like are unlikely to be suitable for you.

Comment: At the top of the output is Entry Id. That is followed by different Sender names, Subject, Received and so on. There is then a line saying "No attachments" or a line saying "Attachments:" followed by a list of attachments. Next is "Text:" followed by "Html:". You found the Html block. The Text block should be above it.

Comment: I have now managed to copy the text. For last column I need to copy text between message and AAA-BBB part.

Comment: @CatBehemoth  How do you identify how many text lines after the keyword “Message” are to be extracted?  For example: all but the last two lines.

Comment: Another possible approach is to start with the Html body and delete everything before <table> and after </table>.  Delete all elements within a table except <tr>, </tr>, <th>, </th>, <td> and </td>. Delete all attributes of <table>, <tr> and <td>.  Delete all whitespace not between <td> and </td>.  This would not be particularly difficult and would leave you with a simple structure that would be easy to decode.  For example: <tr><td>Region</td><td>Europe</td></tr><tr><td>Country</td><td>Switzerland</td></tr>.

Comment: Do you see how each <tr> to </tr> contains a keyword and its value?  The keyword and the value are each bracketed by <td> and </td>.  The final row of the table might be: <tr><td>Message</td><td>Line1<br>Line2<br>Line3</td>.     

To check out this idea, please replace the Html block in your question with everything from line containing the <tr> before “Message” down to the line containing </table>.  Alternately, email me the file Explorer.txt.  My email address is in my profile.

Comment: @CatBehemoth.  Thanks for including all the Html.  I deleted all the formatting by hand so I could see what was left.  I do not think it is worth using the Html.  (1) The Html includes a nested table.  Nested tables can be useful but there seems no purpose in the nesting for this email.  I could ignore the outer table but there is always the fear that it will serve a purpose in another email.  (2) The four lines at the bottom have identical formatting and class.  There is nothing to distinguish the lines you want from the lines you don’t.

Comment: @CatBehemoth.  That leaves my earlier question:  How do you identify how many text lines after the keyword “Message” are to be extracted? For example: all but the last two lines.

Comment: All but last 12 lines. Also, how shall amend the code to parse country, role and product? I am really grateful for all you comments and help

Comment: @CatBehemoth  "All but last 12 lines".  Did you mean "All but last 2 lines".  I have amended macro CopyEmailDataToExcel().  I have replaced the description at the top and have amended the extractions for the new information.  I will replace the original CopyEmailDataToExcel() in my answer with the new version.  The new version ought to work but I have no means of testing it.  You can test it, stepping through the code using F8.  Alternately, you can forward one of these emails to me and I will test it.

Comment: I have run the amended macro and now it parses almost all required fields except role and product. Also, in regards to the message bit is there a way to capture all text between first mention of word message and words AAA-BBB-001366?

Comment: I have amended macro `CopyEmailDataToExcel()` to check for a row containing “AAA-BBB-001366” and, when found, to stop adding rows to the message.  I have changed the way the macro checks for “Country”, “Region”, “Role” and “Product” which might make a difference.  I will update my answer with the new code in a few minutes.  However, as I said, you must debug the code because I cannot.  Is it not finding keywords “Role” and “Product”?  If so, why?  Is it not finding the values associated with keywords “Role” and “Product”?  If so, why?  Do you know how to debug VBA?

Comment: I have just had a horrible thought.  I am assuming the Html and Text bodies in your question are from a genuine email.  Please confirm that you have not faked an email with dummy values using Word?

Comment: Dear Tony, the example email in original question was created in word by me but html and text bodies are from genuine email I just changed some data for security reasons. Also the email i analysed was a forward from a source if that makes any difference.

Comment: (1) That is a relief.  The reason for my concern was that the Html body says it was created using "Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)".  (See: the fourth line of your Html).  That seems a very strange way to create an automatic email since it would be less programming effort to create the Html directly.  (2) Have you tried the new version of my macro?

Comment: It works! Thank you. The only minor issue is that is still captures everything after message. I wonder why is it doing so despite this bit of code `If BodyLines(InxL) = "AAA-BBB-001366`

Comment: @CatBehemoth  Looking back at the text body within your question, I see the terminating value is not "AAA-BBB-001366" but "AAA-BBB-001366 ".  That is, there is a space at the end.  You can add the space to the literal or you could try something like: `If Left$(BodyLines(InxL), 7) = "AAA-BBB" Then`.  The former is the easier but risks the code not working if the space comes and goes.

Comment: @CatBehemoth  It has been a struggle but we got there in the end.  Don't lose my diagnostic routine.  Whenever I am extracting data from an email, I use it to properly understand what the email body contains.

Comment: Yes, that makes it fully functional! Thank you again. I will now grab a cup of tea and try to reverse engineer the code so I can use it in various situations:)

Comment: @CatBehemoth  By the way: come back with questions if you do not understand my code or my reasons for my approach.

Comment: I have used the macro on a few emails and it worked great. But after 3 or 4 i started getting an error message: Runtime error 9 "subscript out of range" and pointing to the row: `.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCountry).Value = BodyLines(InxL)`. What could be the reason?

Comment: @CatBehemoth  `RowCrnt` and `InxL` subscripts.  `ColCountry` is also a subscript but since it is a constant, I do not see how it could be out of range.  Run the macro and, when it stops, hover over RowCrnt and InxL to see their values.  Which seems wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For a message of this format, ignoring further details from the OP.

> Region Europe
>   Country Spain
>   Contactable by email no
>   Contactable by phone no
>   Title MR
>   First name John
>   Last name Doe
>   Email j.doe@doe.com
>   Contact number 1234567
>   Role Customer
>   Institution companyname ltd
>   Product TEST product
>   Message
>   TEST Question

Structured text but with lines without a "**:**" or other unique character between the label and the response. The space is inadequate here, as a unique character, since some labels include a space.

Code for structured text where there is a unique character between the label and the response, [Search structured text in Outlook body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body), will not apply.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration

Sub Extract_noDelimiterToDetermineLabel()

    ' code is in Excel

    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim myOlMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim msgText As String
    'Dim msgLine() As String
    Dim messageArray() As String

    Dim xlObj As Worksheet
    Dim anchor As Range

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ' Unusual technique
    '  Outlook is assumed to be open since a mailitem is selected
    Set myNameSpace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("mapi")
    Set myOlApp = myNameSpace.Parent
    Set objItem = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Set xlObj = ActiveSheet
    Set anchor = xlObj.Range("b2")

    anchor.Offset(0, 0).Value = "Country"
    anchor.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Role"
    anchor.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Product"
    anchor.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Message"
    anchor.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Sender"

    i = 0

    If objItem.Class = olMail Then

        Set myOlMailItem = objItem

        i = i + 1

        msgText = myOlMailItem.Body

        messageArray = Split(msgText, vbCrLf)

        ' Cannot split messageArray elements further since
        '  no character to separate label from response.
        ' Cannot use standard "ParseTextLinePair" code.
        '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body

        For j = 0 To UBound(messageArray)

            If Left(messageArray(j), 4) <> "" Then

                ' The suggested customized technique
                '  depends on there being unique characters to identify the line
                'Debug.Print Left(messageArray(j), 4)

                Select Case Left(messageArray(j), 4)

                    Case "Coun"
                        anchor.Offset(i, 0).Value = Right(messageArray(j), Len(messageArray(j)) - Len("Country "))

                    Case "Role"
                        anchor.Offset(i, 1).Value = Right(messageArray(j), Len(messageArray(j)) - Len("Role "))

                    Case "Prod"
                        anchor.Offset(i, 2).Value = Right(messageArray(j), Len(messageArray(j)) - Len("Product "))

                    Case "Mess"
                        anchor.Offset(i, 3).Value = messageArray(j + 2)

                        anchor.Offset(i, 4).Value = myOlMailItem.SenderName
                        anchor.Offset(i, -1).Value = i

                End Select

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to run the above macro and I get error "run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set" in line `Set anchor = xlObj.Range("b2")`

Comment: No, in outlook.

Comment: Based on the code in the question the code is for Excel. Before you run it go to Outlook and select a test item.

Comment: I will try and come back.  Thanks

Comment: I have tried the code and it copies some bits of the email but to the random cells. I will try to amend the code and see what happens.

Comment: The OP’s original question was very misleading.  The email contains an Html table created using Word.  I would have preferred to extract values from the Html body, but the table is over complicated.  The Text body has two CrLfs between each bit of text.  For example: `Region CrLf CrLf Europe CrLf CrLf Country CrLf CrLf Spain CrLf CrLf`.  So split the Text body on `CrLf & CrLf` and you get one piece of text per line.